# Passing a List through the controller into the IEnumerable view ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have connected sub-category tables to the main table in my models. A structure similar to the one below.

[image: Structure of my sql]

However, I need to access information from different tables (sub-tables) into my main table, "Article". So I have written additional code into my ArticleController in the Index as shown below.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var articles = db.DataToArticles.Include(a => a.AgeGroup).Include(a => a.Disabilities).Include(a => a.StrategyType);

        return View(articles.ToList());
    }
```

"DataToArticles" is similar to the "StrategyTypeToArticle" table above.

Here is my Data Access Layer, which I haven't had any issues with
**DAL:**

```
public class ArticleEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AgeGroup> AgeGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Disabilities> Disabilitiess { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StrategyType> StrategyTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DataToArticle> DataToArticles { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
}
```

Now to my view, which is giving me an error.
 **View**

```
@model IEnumerable<LearningEnterprises.Models.Article>
```

**The Problem**
The issue is passing the articles variable in the controller to my view IEnumberable. I know it is passing it as a List, but I haven't had issues with this before.Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're querying `db.DataToArticles`, you are passing an `IEnumerable<LearningEnterprises.Models.DataToArticle>` to the view rather than an `IEnumerable<LearningEnterprises.Models.Article>`.

Comment: thanks, just did some modifications in my model and controller.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to pass StrategyTypesTo Then you will get the articles and var articles may not be article type no more since you pass so much  extra there

to make it easy   you can use dynamics or try what other post suggests

```
List<dynamic> articles = db.DataToArticles.Include(a => a.AgeGroup).Include(a => a.Disabilities).Include(a => a.StrategyType);

@model List<dynamic>
```